# Query datatable using linq to get count order by

Tags: .net, linq

I have a DataTable something like shown below. i need to query it using linq

Something like this Query in linq

```
select B, Count(C)
from DataTable
group by B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.DataTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.B)
    .Select(new { B = x.Key, CountC = x.Count(y => y.C) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var qry = datatable1.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(a=>a.Field<type>("FieldB"))
    .Select(grp=>new
          {
             value = grp.Key,
             count = grp.Count(c=>c.Field<type>("FieldC"))
          });
```

Replace `type` with proper data type, such as: `int`, `string`, etc.